# No Google Drive files are listed in Drive API request

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to get a list of the files in my Google Drive using a desktop app. The code is as follows:

```
def main(argv):

    storage = Storage('drive.dat')
    credentials = storage.get()

    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

    # Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
    # with our good Credentials.
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    service = build("drive", "v2", http=http)
    retrieve_all_files(service)
```

Then in retrieve_all_files, I print the files:

```
param = {}
if page_token:
    param['pageToken'] = page_token
    files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
    print files
```

But after I authenticate to my account, the printed file list has no items. Does anyone have a similar problem or know of a solution to this?

Comment: Can you paste the whole of retrieve_all_files? It looks like a useful function.

Comment: @AliAfshar,you can find it here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Answer (score 6):

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I believe you are using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope, which only returns files that your app has created or have been explicitly opened with your app using the [Google Drive UI](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_open_with_contextual_menu) or the [`Picker API`](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open#open_and_upload_files_using_the_google_picker).

To retrieve all files, you will need to use the broader scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

To learn more about the different scopes, have a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes).

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but still there is no content in the returned list...

Comment: Is the source available anywhere so we can get a shot at trying to reproduce? Please make sure to remove `drive.dat` when you change the scope as it might use an old token that hasn't bee approved for the broader scope.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you need to iterate through page_token in order to get all the contents of My Drive as well as any subfolders. There are a few other things it could be too like not providing a query, etc. Try this:

```
def retrieve_all_files(service):
    """ RETURNS a list of files, where each file is a dictionary containing
        keys: [name, id, parents]
    """

    query = "trashed=false"

    page_token = None
    L = []

    while True:
        response = service.files().list(q=query,
                                             spaces='drive',
                                             fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)',
                                             pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for file in response.get('files', []):  # The second argument is the default
            L.append({"name":file.get('name'), "id":file.get('id'), "parents":file.get('parents')})

        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)  # The second argument is the default

        if page_token is None:  # The base My Drive folder has None
            break

    return L
```